# jQuery .is(':checked') returns wrong value

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

Essentially I have a table with checkboxes on the first column of each row (the rest of the table is just configuration options, and each row is its own set of options, which are only saved if that checkbox is checked). At the top of the table there's a select-all/deselect-all checkbox, and using that is sort of where my problem arises. The select-all works just fine from what displays on the UI, but later when I go through some validation the value that's pulled from the checkboxes is incorrect.

Just unchecking and checking the fields by hand seems to work alright. But once I use the select-all, the values are always `true`.

So, the expected result: the select-all properly updates the values (or has a better way of getting the values via jQuery or plain Javascript, whichever). I'm guessing there's something wrong with how I'm updating the values in select-all, but I haven't found any alternatives to what I'm trying to accomplish that work.

```
// there is more in the class, but as far as what I think the question needs:
public class SomeModel
{
    public bool _UseThisRow { get; set; }
}


@model Models.SomeModel
@{
}

<script type="text/javascript">

    function ValidateSelections(){
        var isChk = $('[name="@nameof(Model._UseThisRow)"]').is(':checked');
        if(isChk){
         alert('error');
        }
    }

    $('#opt-all').change(function(){
        var val = $(this).is(":checked");

        $('[name="@nameof(Model._UseThisRow)"]').prop('checked', val);
        // and several more of these^ for the rest of the checkboxes
    }

    $('#submit').click(function(){
        if(ValidateSelections()){
            // do stuff
        }
    }

</script>

<div>
    <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-stripted table-responsive" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="text-align:center;width:30px;"> 
                    <input type="checkbox" id="opt-all" />
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr> 
                <td style=text-align: center;" id="@nameof(Model._UseThisRow>
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m._UseThisRow)
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table> 
</div>
```

Comment: Side note; you should avoid performing `$(this).is(':checked')` as it is unnecessary overhead when `this.checked` will already give you true/false.  The overhead comes from having to instantiate a jQuery object, and then execute a method which then processes a pseudo-selector against the element to see if it matches.  That pseudo-selector is essentially going to do the same validation against the checked property that you already had access to.  So that should be avoided.

Comment: Also it would be nice if you could make a [mcve] to show the issue.  Just reading the question it's not entirely clear with the error is introduced.  My first thought is `is(':checked')` will return true for a jQuery object if *any* of the elements in the result stack are checked.

Comment: @Taplar Editing the question, but there isn't much outside of what I have posted

Comment: Please make an [mcve] demonstrating the issue.

Comment: @Taplar updated the question

Comment: Please replace your templating logic with actual generated markup.  That's not a reproducable example.  Edit your question and click the `<>` button or hit CTRL+M to bring up the onsite editor.  A reproducable example is a runnable example.  You should be able to right click and inspect your actual page to grab the generated markup.

Comment: Unfortunately there is not enough in your question in order to be able to answer it.  There are a number of differences between what you describe and what your almost-but-not-right code that it is difficult to tell the difference between what you mistyped, translated incorrectly, and what the issue you describe is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `$('#opt-all').change(function(){` callback, I ended up replacing the code that checks/unchecks with more 'DOM' oriented code, instead of just native jQuery.

Instead of this:
`$('[name="@nameof(Model._UseThisRow)"]').prop('checked', val);`

I used this: `$('[name="@nameof(Model._UseThisRow)"]')[0].checked = val;`